# image link to an external page in JS

Tags: javascript

I have this js code

```
window.addEvent("domready", function () {
  var maxLength = 700;
  var counterFluid = 1;
  var wallFluid = new Wall("wall", {
    "width":180,
    "height":180,
    "rangex":[-14,21],
    "rangey":[-8,12],
    callOnUpdate: function (items) {
      items.each(function (e, i) {
        var a = new Element("img[src=images/"+counterFluid+".jpg]");
        counterFluid++;
        if( counterFluid > maxLength ) counterFluid = 1;
      });
    }
  });
  wallFluid.initWall();
});
```

This results in displaying images in an array. Now I would like to add links to images such that when the image is clicked it opens a new page.

I tried this code

```
a.onclick = function () {
  window.location.href = '/"+counterFluid+".html';
};
```

A new page is opening but the url just shows as /"+counterFluid+".html

I know that this is not correct. Kindly help. The URL for each image will be different so trying to use +counterFluid+

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = "/" + counterFluid + ".html";
```

Try it like this with only ".

Comment: this works but it gives random numbers. The number for image & link should be same. Is it possible. Also the link should open in tab.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the id attribute of the image to store the 'counterFluid' var like this:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('id', counterFluid);
img.setAttribute('src', 'images/' + counterFluid + '.jpg');
img.onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = '/' + this.id + '.html';
}
```